# Custom hook not updating in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that looks roughly like this:

```js
export default function useMyHook() {
  const [foo, _setFoo] = useState([]);
  const [bar, setBar] = useState(null);
  const setFoo = (arg) => {
    _setFoo(arg);
    const newBar = getBar(arg);
    setBar(newBar);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(bar); // this prints when bar changes
  }, [bar]);

  return {
    foo,
    bar,
    setFoo,
  };
}
```

And this hook is used like this:

```js
export const function MyComp(): React.MixedElement {
  const {foo} = useMyHook()

  console.log(foo) // prints null once
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(foo) // doesn't print
  }, [foo])

  return foo ? (
    <div>This doesn't render</div>
  ) : (
    <div>This renders</div>
  )
}
```

The `setFoo()` is called in different component to set foo. When that happens, `bar` changes, and runs the `useEffect` callback, but not in the component.

What is happening here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You code [works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-goodall-z4ecyh?file=/src/App.js), please provide a [mre].

Comment: "The setFoo() is called in different component to set foo" - this sounds like a misunderstanding of how hooks work. They don't share state between component instances. There is really nothing special about hooks; its the same as having the functionality in the body of component, expect the return values are memoised internally by React, and they can be reused. What you're talking about sounds closer to React Context.

Comment: @lawrence-witt I think that's the answer: "not sharing state between components." I guess I have to look into this `useContext` or something?

Comment: @lawrence-witt Is exactly correct. React hooks don't share state unless they all consume it from a single "context". Do you need help from here or do you want to go research a bit and try something on your own first?

Comment: @DrewReese I think I'm good. I'm going to look into my options now then come back if I need to.

Comment: Sure thing. If/when you do, and you still have an issue, you should update this question with your new findings and code.